# Wordpress PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a login page for my site using PHP.  I developed it on my local computer and it works with no issues however I have put it on Wordpress and now the page will not login due to the $_SESSION not having the key ***'UserName'***.

I investigated the issue and found that the $_SESSION data is not saving/setting due to when I `print_r($_SESSION)` it returns `Array()`.  How do I use `$_SESSION` on Wordpress?

this is at the top of my index.php page

```
if (!session_id()) 
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['UserName'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

And on login.php (what is setting the infomation)

```
if (!session_id()) 
session_start();

$_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['UserID'];
$_SESSION['UserName'] = $_POST['user']; // Leave decrypted
$_SESSION['Password'] = $pass; // Leave encrypted
```

I assume wordpress does it differently. Could someone please explain.

Comment: Curious, why don't you use wordpress's tools for this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Comment: I am using one of my web apps I wrote, all the code works on my computer (XAMPP) but not on the main web server.  I would rather do it like this so I don't have to rewrite it.

Comment: 100% have a look at WordPress functionality for this is you're doing this within WordPress... you can hook in in using wp-load.php and get access to all the WP functions outside of WP itself too

Comment: I also need to know how $_SESSION works for other parts of my site.  Do I have to use plugins to do it or can it just be though the PHP I already wrote?